# SIGABRT when using avcapturepreviewlayer initwithsessionwithnoconnection

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I am trying to develop an app that uses two `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayers`.

Using

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *a = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
```

works just fine.

However, using

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *a = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSessionWithNoConnection:session];
```

gives me a SIGABRT with the following message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer initWithSessionWithNoConnection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155547e0'

I am using XCode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a) and Mavericks.

Any help would be appreciated.

///////////////////////////////////////

/* UPDATE */
1. Stasel - thanks for the formatting.

2. I figured it out.

After checking the header file AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.h, the declaration I was looking for to initWithSessionWithNoConnection is only available for iOS 8 and later.

Case solved!  Now I just gotta buy an iPhone 6!!